# Show that $X_{J}: \Omega_{T} \to \Omega_{J}$ is $\mathcal{F}^{\otimes T}-$measurable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $T$ be uncountable and $J$ be countable.
Show that: 
$X_{J}: \Omega_{T} \to \Omega_{J}$ is $\mathcal{F}^{\otimes T}-$measurable

My idea:

Note that $\mathcal{F}^{\otimes T}$ on $\Omega_{T}$ is the smallest sigma-algebra so that all one-dimensional projections are measurable. Now consider the product-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}^{\otimes J}$ and $A\in \mathcal{F}^{\otimes J}$

$X_{J}^{-1}(A)=\bigcap\limits_{j \in J}X_{j}^{-1}(A_{j})$ where $A_{j}$ is chosen in such a way that $\times_{i \in J\setminus \{j\}}A_{i}\times A_{j}=A$

But my problem is that $J$ is countable and not necessarily finite, hence it is not necessarily true that $\bigcap\limits_{j \in J}X_{j}^{-1}(A_{j})\in \mathcal{F}^{\otimes T}$

Comment: You might want to add the definition of $X_J$. I suppose it's the projection, but it's not clear from the statement of your problem. Regarding your question: sigma-algebras are stable under countable intersections, i.e. if $(F_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{F}$, then $\bigcap_{j \in \mathbb{N}} F_j \in \mathcal{F}$. This should do the job, right?